# How to enable "Stay awake" by defoult in android OS in firmware level

Tags: android

My issue is Android goes to sleep mode, i can avoid this by selecting from settings but that is not what i want. 
I would like to change the stay awake option from firmware level and/or ??(smarter way) so that i can have my new build with the stay awake selected by default permanent and forever, but i do not find the source files.
-is the power manager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#FULL_WAKE_LOCK) really the only option? any other solutions?

Edit: wake_lock.c and .h files are handling the topic, so is that where the stay awake mechanism handled?

Regards, Archer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stay awake option from developers option is changed in defaults.xml:
-    false
+    true

-Index: android/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsProvider/res/values/defaults.xml

Once the flag is changed to "true" the system does not go to sleep.
Cheers,
Archer